# django-compressor + less compress the files but link to original files

Tags: django, less, django-compressor

I'm having a django 1.4.2 app with django-compressor 1.2 used to compress a less file.

I have my less file in **app/static/css/home.less.**
It outputs a less file under **static/CACHE/css/5208013a00a2.css**

When running locally (Debug=True, the files are served by django) i'm getting a correct response. the following output in my html (template) file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/CACHE/css/5208013a00a2.css" type="text/css">
```

When running in deployment (Apache serves the files) i'm having a bad response. the following output in my html file:

```
<link type="text/less" rel="stylesheet" href="/adduplicator/static/css/home.less" charset="utf-8">
```

The files gets created in deploy under **static/CACHE/css/5208013a00a2.css** so i'm assuming there is no permission problems. I get nothing wrong in the logs.

some of the settings from settings.py:

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/coffeescript', 'coffee --compile --stdio'),
    ('text/less', 'lessc {infile} {outfile}'),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)
```

The deploy is made through fabric, and it creates the app under virtual env.

Comment: Two things I can think of: is your `lessc` compiler available on the server? And secondly, are there differences between your production and development settings?

Comment: well you are partly right. lessc wasn't available. installed it through:
sudo apt-get install npm; sudo npm install less -g.
But still, that didn't help. the difference between settings are debug true and debug false. one serves the static files and the other isn't

Comment: Apache needs to be configured to serve your static files. Django won't do this with `DEBUG=False` as the built-in server is not very performant for static files.

Comment: @MichaelMior it's not related. as the other js, css files are served perfectly. it's working with mod_wsgi.

Comment: @GalBracha Ah, alright. Nevermind my comment then :)

Comment: After installing lessc, did you restart your wsgi process? Staticfiles has to know it can now compile them.

Comment: @ReinoutvanRees yes. didn't help

Comment: Is `COMPRESS_OFFLINE` set to `False` (or unset in which case it is)?

Comment: @Streeter Yes, Played with this one. didn't help

Comment: What does the error actually say? Are you getting a 404 on the compressed file? The other thing I always forget to do is run `collectstatic`

Answer (score 0):

I believe

`('text/less', 'lessc {infile} {outfile}'),`

should be

`('text/less', 'lessc {infile} > {outfile}'),`

as without the redirect lessc will compile to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not apply to the original poster, but I experienced the exact same error (.less files getting linked instead of being replaced by the generated CSS) and it was because I had recently set Django to run as a normal user instead of root, and hence didn't have permission to write to the cache folder that it created as root. `chown -R myuser:mygroup static/cache` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue, my setup is nearly identical to yours (using apache, debug=False, etc.), and haven't resolved it yet.  I have found that if I manually run compress (python manage.py compress), it will resolve the issue, but it will only resolve it temporarily.  After 6-12 hours the issue will recur.

There is nothing dynamic in the .css/.js files that I'm compressing - I'm using django compressor as a means of precompiling my lessc and coffeescript.

I hope you found a workaround last fall when you ran into this issue - for anyone else having the same problem, try manually running compress.  I don't know why this helps, since the files are already there in the CACHE, but for some reason it does (temporarily).  I'll update when I resolve.

EDIT:  Problem has not recurred in the past 12 days.  I'm still a little sketched out that there was a problem and I didn't understand the resolution, but for now it's working so I'm focusing on other stuff.  If you have an issue of this nature, please post or comment.

Recommended steps if you have this issue:

1. Verify that the files are generated in the CACHE directory
2. Look at ownership of the files, and the CACHE directories, and chown them if necessary
3. Look at timestamps of the files in CACHE, verify that they're reasonable
4. Run collectstatic and compress manually, then restart the server (kill & restart if you're using python runserver, or sudo service
   apache2 restart, or other equivalent)